# Bitmap.createScaledBitmap Error

Tags: android, memory

This code falls on some devices with 16mb VM heap limit on the line

image.bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, dstWidth, dstHeight, true);

from the scaleFrom method.

Bitmap.Options did not help at all. Any advise or insight for more effient approach is greatly appreciated.

Please view Java file attached.

[ScaleBitmap.java](http://www.mediafire.com/?k996vn166x6ru68)

NOTE:

Images are being scaled up according to screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following link:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13736#c2